# Using z-index to position something in front of an svg

Tags: css, svg, z-index

I'm well aware that I can't apply z-index to an svg, and that for svgs, z-index is defined by the order the element appears in the document.

But suppose I have a div (not an svg) that I want to force to be in front of that svg, and for other reasons, that div needs to occur later on in the markup, like this:

```
<svg>...</svg>
<div style="z-index=9999999; position: relative;">...</div>
```

(The above results in the svg still being in front)

Is there any way to force the div to be in front besides moving it up above the HTML in the markup?

Comment: You can position the div can't you?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't **re-use** the SVG as a background to the div. That's possible isn't it?

Comment: We're using skrollr (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) to create what is basically a layered game world - I have several layers of svgs on top of each other, with other HTML elements living on those layers - moving the div in question to another layer isn't really an option here.

Comment: Paulie_D - I'm not sure how re-using the SVG as a background to the div would help - the original SVG would still be in front of the div, no?

Comment: Huangism - what do you mean "position the div"? I can move it around w/ absolute or relative coordinates - but I can't seem to bring it in front of the svg.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue, so I put this little fiddle together to hopefully help. http://jsfiddle.net/R3aLZ/. I put an .svg image in a div, then change the z-index on all of the divs, and am able to move them around freely (just click on the buttons).

Comment: Thanks TimSPQR!  The issue turned out to be w/ something that I didn't think was relevant (and so didn't include in the question) - both the svg and the div were wrapped in other divs that had "position: fixed" on them - that was what was causing the layering issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't include enough information in the question... my actual code looked more like this:

```
<div style="position: fixed">
  <svg>...</svg>
</div>
<div style="position: fixed">
   <div style="z-index: 9999999; position: relative;">...</div>
</div>
```

It was the position:fixed that was preventing the z-indexed div from appearing in front of the svg - see http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements for more info: as of Chrome 22, "All position:fixed elements now form new stacking contexts." - that is, z-indices are relative to each other w/in a position: fixed element.